# How to use dbt's incremental model without duplicates

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I have a query that selects some data that I would like to use to create an incremental table. Something like:

```
{{
    config(
        materialized='incremental',
        unique_key='customer_id'
    )
}}
SELECT
    customer_id,
    email,
    updated_at,
    first_name,
    last_name
FROM data
```

The input data has duplicate customers in it. If I read the documentation correctly, then records with the same unique_key should be seen as the same record. They should be updated instead of creating duplicates in the final table. However, I am seeing duplicates in the final table instead. What am I doing wrong?

I am using Snowflake as a datawarehouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your source table already contains the duplicate, this is the regular behavior.

As per dbt documentation: "The first time a model is run, the table is built by transforming all rows of source data."

Docs: https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/incremental-models

This means basically that the duplicates will be avoided in all future loads, but not during the initial creation. Hence you need to change your SELECT statement so that duplicates are somehow filtered out in the creation itself.

Answer (score 1):

With incremental materialization dbt would do a merge or delete-insert using the `unique_key`. I believe in the case of Snowflake it's doing a [merge](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/merge.html). This means that running the same model several times won't write the same records over and over again to the target table.

If you experience duplicates, most likely your select returns duplicate records. You'd need to deduplicate your input data, which is often done with `row_number()` function, something like:

```sql
(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY {{ timestamp_column }} DESC) = 1) AS is_latest
```

and then filtering by `WHERE is_latest`